# jsonpath_ng.lexer.JsonPathLexerError: Error on line 1, col 8: Unexpected character: /

Tags: python, jsonpath

I am using jsonpath_ng library to build a jsonpath expression.But getting error while parsing expression as expression contains /. 
jsonpath_ng.lexer.JsonPathLexerError: Error on line 1, col 8: Unexpected character: /

Tried jsonpath_rw_ext,jsonpath_ng.ext libraries ,still facing similar errors.

````
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath,parse
jsonpath_expression = parse('$.paths./createJob.post.parameters[0].schema.$ref') ```
````

Answer (score 2):

The error is arising because the jsonpath_ng library appears to interpret the `/` symbol as numeric division, not as a valid character in identifiers.

At the same time, however, it's unusual (though not impossible) for the JSON to have `/` characters in property names.

As I see it, what you need to do depends on the data you have:

1. If your JSON genuinely has a `/` character in property names, i.e. it looks like the following:

   ```
   {"paths": {"/createJob": {"post": ... } } }
   ```

   then you'll need to use the bracket notation (`['propertyname']`) instead of the dot notation (`.propertyname`):

   ```
   jsonpath_expression = parse("$.paths['/createJob'].post.parameters[0].schema.$ref")
   ```
2. If your JSON doesn't actually have `/` characters in property names, then you should just delete the `/` from your JSON Path expression.

Note that I cannot guarantee either of these approaches to return data, because you haven't provided any sample data to query nor the expected result of running the JSON Path query.

Comment: Hi @Luke Woodward ,
My Json have genuinely has / characters in property name.Using (['propertyname'])  did solved my problem. 
Thanks a lot.